# Playwright - Selecting link with nth-match and value in href

Tags: javascript, playwright

I have a page, where I need to select a link. The links on the page are (for example):

```
<a href="/animation?ID=11111\&amp;model\_id=AAAAA">Preview Results</a>
<a href="/animation?ID=11111\&amp;model\_id=BBBBB">Preview Results</a>
<a href="/animation?ID=22222\&amp;model\_id=CCCCC">Preview Results</a>
<a href="/animation?ID=22222\&amp;model\_id=DDDDD">Preview Results</a>
<a href="/animation?ID=33333\&amp;model\_id=EEEEE">Preview Results</a>
<a href="/animation?ID=33333\&amp;model\_id=FFFFF">Preview Results</a>
```

The link I need is the first instance of `ID=22222`

I can get the first Preview Results link:

```js
await page.locator(':nth-match(a:has-text("Preview Results"), 1)').click();
```

But how can I get the first ID link (of ID `22222`)?

Answer (score 5):

This seems like a good use case for [CSS attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```js
const playwright = require("playwright"); // ^1.30.1

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<a href="/animation?ID=11111\&amp;model\_id=AAAAA">Preview Results</a>
<a href="/animation?ID=11111\&amp;model\_id=BBBBB">Preview Results</a>
<a href="/animation?ID=22222\&amp;model\_id=CCCCC">Preview Results</a>
<a href="/animation?ID=22222\&amp;model\_id=DDDDD">Preview Results</a>
<a href="/animation?ID=33333\&amp;model\_id=EEEEE">Preview Results</a>
<a href="/animation?ID=33333\&amp;model\_id=FFFFF">Preview Results</a>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await playwright.chromium.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const loc = page.locator('[href*="ID=22222"]');
  console.log(await loc.first().getAttribute("href"));
    // => /animation?ID=22222&model_id=CCCCC
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

A couple of variants to consider:

```js
page.locator('[href*="ID=22222"]', {hasText: "Preview Results"});
```

```js
page.locator('[href*="ID=22222"][href*="id=CCCCC"]');
```

Answer (score 2):

I was not great at outlining the issue in my initial post, apologies.
This is what I ended up going with:

```
await page.getByRole('row', { name: /. 22222./ })
  .getByRole('link', { name: 'Preview Results' })
  .first()
  .click();
```